# What happens to demand economics when rates are negative?

Tags: macroeconomics

Keynesian economics assumes falling lending opportunity lowers profit.

Under negative rates less lending actually means More Profit. So how does this change things?

Comment: This _may_ help: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/17241/175

Answer (score 0):

Over the past several years, we have seen many countries that have risk free debt yield negative returns. Even [some corporate bonds](https://www.barrons.com/articles/yields-go-negative-on-corporate-bonds-not-just-government-debt-51562942845) are yielding negative returns now. However, most corporate debt and riskier debt still yields positive returns. And I expect it will be a long while (if ever) before the entire risk curve is yielding negative returns.

While this may be a concern for other reasons, it doesn't change the fact that "falling lending opportunity lowers profit". The less positive yielding debt that exists, the less opportunities to profitably lend. And while I am dubious of the sustainability, [negative yielding debt can apparently be profitable too](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/that-near17-trillion-pile-of-negative-yielding-global-debt-its-a-cash-cow-for-some-bond-investors-2019-08-22). Keynesian ideas will be relevant for a long while.

In fact, one of the most relevant concepts in a world of negative yielding debt is the notion of a [liquidity trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquidity_trap), which was originally popularized by John Maynard Keynes. To combat this, in the next recession, we may see more unconventional monetary policy ideas like [helicopter money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter_money) be implemented.

Answer (score -1):

When interest rates are negative the entire point of keynesian economics is reversed and doesn't work.

Interest has been negative for a long time with subprime etc. It's just now obvious.

We need a new economics to deal with this situation.

Comment: (-1) Risk free interest rates may have been negative for a while in some countries but riskier debt has positive interest rates. Keynesian ideas will be relevant for a long while.